# How to identify a set of objects from a large number of possible set combinations; efficient structures or models

Tags: java, c#, math, data-structures, processing-efficiency

I've been battling a problem I have and I can seem to figure out how to solve it. I will not give the exact problem but I will translate it into a simpler form. This is the simplest form I came up with:

**PROBLEM:**

You have an object type with some properties: ex. Object OBJ(p1, p2, z)

You have 4 sets: A, B, C, D; which consists of objects like the one above. Each set has 80 objects. (80 A objects, 80 B objects, so on. It's a DB with them.)

As input I'm giving Z = zA + zB + zC + zD. In words Z is the sum of 'z's from a set.

I am interested in a result set which looks like R(Ax, Bx, Cx, Dx), where 'x', represents the index (it can be from 1 to 80).

The one which is the biggest. FORMULA: (approx :D, its a number)

BIGGEST = coef1*(Ap1+Bp1+Cp1+Dp1) + coef2*(Ap2+Bp2+Cp2+Dp2)

coef1 and coef2 - coeficients; A, B, C, D OBJ objects; p1 and p2 object properties.

**HOW I DO IT**;         maybe there is a better way??

I am putting all the result sets which have Z smaller or equal to the given Z in a list. ex R1(A1, B1, C1, D1); R2(A1, B1, C1, D2) and so on. 80x80x80x80 = 41 mil combinations (approx)

Then I search the list for the biggest SET which is calculated with the formula above.

**WHAT I NEED**

1. I'm getting stack overflow when creating the result list when it's too big(it can have up to 41 million entries, It cracks after around(max) 6 mil entries)
2. It takes so long to calculate(find the biggest set), how can I reduce the time (threads, smth else?)
3. Completely new solution, take on the problem.

I write the code in C# (Visual Studio). I am not looking for the complete code for this problem but guidelines and/or possibly new takes on it. I'm thinking my method is not very good for it.

Thank you!

This is how I do it now:

```
public static void CalculateArmorStats(string selectedHead, string selectedChest, string selectedHands, string selectedLegs)
    {
        #region variable
        double strike; double slash; double thrust; 
        double magic; double fire; double lightning; double dark; 
        if (!selectedHead.Contains("Name =")) selectedHead = "Name ='" + selectedHead + "'";
        if (!selectedChest.Contains("Name =")) selectedChest = "Name ='" + selectedChest + "'";
        if (!selectedHands.Contains("Name =")) selectedHands = "Name ='" + selectedHands + "'";
        if (!selectedLegs.Contains("Name =")) selectedLegs = "Name ='" + selectedLegs + "'";
        MainWindow.possibleArmors = MainWindow.possibleArmors + 1;
        #endregion variable

        #region calculate stats  
        strike = double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHead.Select(selectedHead).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(4).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbChest.Select(selectedChest).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(4).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHands.Select(selectedHands).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(4).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbLegs.Select(selectedLegs).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(4).ToString());
        slash = double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHead.Select(selectedHead).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(5).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbChest.Select(selectedChest).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(5).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHands.Select(selectedHands).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(5).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbLegs.Select(selectedLegs).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(5).ToString());
        thrust = double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHead.Select(selectedHead).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(6).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbChest.Select(selectedChest).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(6).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHands.Select(selectedHands).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(6).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbLegs.Select(selectedLegs).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(6).ToString());
        magic = double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHead.Select(selectedHead).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(7).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbChest.Select(selectedChest).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(7).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHands.Select(selectedHands).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(7).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbLegs.Select(selectedLegs).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(7).ToString());
        fire = double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHead.Select(selectedHead).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(8).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbChest.Select(selectedChest).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(8).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHands.Select(selectedHands).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(8).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbLegs.Select(selectedLegs).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(8).ToString());
        lightning = double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHead.Select(selectedHead).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(9).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbChest.Select(selectedChest).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(9).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHands.Select(selectedHands).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(9).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbLegs.Select(selectedLegs).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(9).ToString());
        dark = double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHead.Select(selectedHead).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(10).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbChest.Select(selectedChest).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(10).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbHands.Select(selectedHands).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(10).ToString())
        + double.Parse(MainWindow.dbLegs.Select(selectedLegs).Single().ItemArray.ElementAt(10).ToString());
        #endregion calculate stats

        #region calculate armor
        if (strike + slash + thrust > MainWindow.physicalVerifier)
        {
            MainWindow.physicalVerifier = strike + slash + thrust;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[0].headArmor = selectedHead;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[0].chestArmor = selectedChest;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[0].handsArmor = selectedHands;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[0].legsArmor = selectedLegs;              
        }
        if (magic + fire + lightning + dark > MainWindow.elementalVerifier)
        {
            MainWindow.elementalVerifier = magic + fire + lightning + dark;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[1].headArmor = selectedHead;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[1].chestArmor = selectedChest;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[1].handsArmor = selectedHands;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[1].legsArmor = selectedLegs;
        }
        if (strike + slash + thrust + 0.7 * (magic + fire + lightning + dark) > MainWindow.overallVerifier)
        {
            MainWindow.overallVerifier = strike + slash + thrust + 0.7 * (magic + fire + lightning + dark);
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[2].headArmor = selectedHead;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[2].chestArmor = selectedChest;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[2].handsArmor = selectedHands;
            MainWindow.SELECTEDARMOR[2].legsArmor = selectedLegs;
        }
        #endregion  calculate armor            
    }
```

And then I call The following FOR (and it takes 3 minutes to calculate - how can I reduce this time):

```
        foreach (ArmorObject chestItem in MainWindow.CHESTS)
        {
            foreach (ArmorObject legsItem in MainWindow.LEGS)
            {
                foreach (ArmorObject handsItem in MainWindow.HANDS)
                {
                    if (availableWeight >= double.Parse(chestItem.weight.ToString()) + double.Parse(legsItem.weight.ToString())
                        + double.Parse(handsItem.weight.ToString()))
                    {
                        string selectedHead = MainWindow.mySlectedArmorName.head.Content.ToString();
                        string selectedChest = chestItem.name;
                        string selectedHands = handsItem.name;
                        string selectedLegs = legsItem.name;
                        CalculateArmorStats(selectedHead, selectedChest, selectedHands, selectedLegs);
                    }
                }                                
            }                        
        }
```

Ok, back with another update.
So I did the following:

I put the 4 databases (head, chest, ...) in 4 lists of objects. -> This makes the program start up slower but not by much.

Now when I calculate the data I need not to interogate the DB (region calculate stats) -> This reduce the time of the FOR I posted here from 3 minutes to 3 seconds.

However I am still not happy or agree that this is a solution (it does help me) because my DBs are small compared to a real life project :D .

Comment: It's better if you provide us a `code` based on how you attempted this, giving us bunch of `xyz` variables doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have

- objects that have three properties `p1`, `p2`, and `z`,
- four sets `A`, `B`, `C` and `D` with 80 of the above objects each,
- two constants `k1` and `k2`,
- a function `f(a,b,c,d)=k1*(a.p1+b.p1+c.p1+d.p1) + k2*(a.p2+b.p2+c.p2+d.p2)` which maps elements of `A×B×C×D` to a value,
- a function `g(a,b,c,d)=a.z+b.z+c.z+d.z` which maps elements of `A×B×C×D` to a value,
- an input value `Z` and
- a value `BIGGEST` which is the maximum value of `f(a,b,c,d)` over the set `A×B×C×D` (or maybe - I didn't quite get that from your problem formulation - only over those elements of `A×B×C×D` that fulfill `g(a,b,c,d)≤Z`),

and you want to calculate a set `S` which contains all elements of `A×B×C×D` with `f(a,b,c,d)=BIGGEST` and `g(a,b,c,d)≤Z`.

If this is the case, you can split your problem into two parts:

1. Find the value `BIGGEST`. This does not need much memory, as you can store the highest value found so far and update it if you find a higher value.
2. Generate the set `S`: Having already calculated `BIGGEST`, this is also easy. If you don't store the found elements of the set `S`, this also does not need much memory.

Comment: Added my current code. If you have any suggestions I will appreciate. The for has to calculate 90x90x90 posibilities and I also posted my calculus method. I want to reduce it's time to under a minute. Have no idea how to do it.